# Which keys are used to activate substitution in Ultimate Ninja Storm 2?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2

Which keys are use to activate substitution in Ultimate Ninja Storm 2 on PC?

Comment: What console are you playing this on?

Comment: PC? Ultimate Ninja Storm 2 is only available for the Xbox 360 and Playstation 3.

Answer (score 1):

While playing as that character in free battle, press start and go to ‘Combo List’.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that the game isn't available on the PC, here's the answer:

Substitution Jutsu is activated by pressing the same button you would use for guarding/blocking just before an attack would hit you. If the attack was a melee attack, you would be placed behind your opponent, ready to retaliate, and if the attack was a ranged attack you would simply appear above your current position, avoiding the attack.

On the PS3, the default buttons for blocking are R2 and L2 (the lower shoulder buttons) and on the Xbox 360 the default buttons are the corresponding LT and RT.